# About me box in profile stopped supporting unicode

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, unicode

I used to have unicode in my profile page

> ˙uʍop-ǝpısdn sı ɹoʇıuoɯ ɹnoʎ 'sıɥʇ pɐǝɹ uɐɔ noʎ ɟı

which showed up fine but now shows gibberish. Same happens to more mainstream unicode

e.g Hebrew

> My name in Hebrew is **מוטי**

Note the text shows up fine in the preview but here's what it looks like when saved.

[image]

---

**Edit:** I've edited my profile page [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3848/motti) to show the problem, the same problem does **not** show up on [area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/8235/motti).

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Seems to be working on Area 51, but not here.

Comment: Your upside-down text works fine for me with FF and Chrome. I have no idea where your Hebrew name should show up. Linking would help.

Comment: @Ladybug, where does it look fine? In the post it's OK but when I put it in the **About me** section of the profile page I get the attached screen shot (in Firefox an Chrome on Windows).

Comment: @Motti: here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/8235/motti - The only place, where I see something different than "I'm just this guy, y'know?"

Comment: @Ladybug, as @Kobi said it works fine in area51 but not on SO or meta (see my profile page). The data isn't lost, if I click edit I get the original Unicode string back it just doesn't render.

Comment: Same on my profile, of course: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7586/kobi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed - check your profile!

Comment: @moguzalp sure, you can use whatever language you want.